# Structure null character(\0) issue with strings in C programming Language

Tags: c, string, c-strings, null-terminated

Is the below issue happening because of null character. 'Yes/No'. Please explain why.

**First code**

```
#include<stdio.h>  
    struct date{  char day[2];  char month[2];  char year[4];  
    }current_date;

    void main(){
    printf("Enter day: ");     
    scanf("%s",current_date.day);
    printf("Enter month: ");
    scanf("%s",current_date.month);
    printf("Enter year: ");
    scanf("%s",current_date.year);
    printf("\nEntered date is: 
    %s/%s/%s",current_date.day,current_date.month,current_date.year)
    }
```

**Input:**
If I enter **17,02,1998** respectively for each scan.
**Output:**

```
Entered date is: 17021998/021998/1998
```

**Second code** for the same input when I just change the array length in structure.

```
#include<stdio.h>  
    struct date{  char day[3];  char month[3];  char year[5];  
    }current_date;
```

**Rest the whole code is same.**
**Output**

```
Entered date is: 17/02/1998
```

Please explain me this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: A "string" in C in fact is a `0`-terminated `char`-array. The `0` needs to go somewhere.

Comment: You need to increase the size of each char array by (at least) 1 to make room for the `\0` character.

Comment: Note that this could also cause some nasty side effect. Because there is no space for the '\0' after the year array, this '\0' is still written in the next memory byte after the end of the class. Depending on what is stored there, you could end up corrupting your data.

Answer (score 1):

In [c](/questions/tagged/c), a string is not an intrinsic type. A C-string is the convention to have a one-dimensional array of characters which is terminated by a null-character, by a `'\0'`.

Using that knowledge it should be

```
 struct date{  char day[3];  char month[3];  char year[5];
```

Otherwise `scanf`<sup>1</sup> won't be able to store the `\0` ***within*** the array and it would be undefined behavior if you try to get `2` digit input (for `day` or `month` or `4` digit year by using `%s` format specifier) with it - because `scanf` will try to write it beyond the array and that would be [***Undefined Behaviour***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The `scanf` usage would be

```
if(scanf("%2s",current_date.day)!=1){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

The way you defined your structure - would give you `1` digit month, `1` digit day and `3` digit year if you store the corresponding `\0` also. That is not what you want. In `C` strings are realized using nul terminated `char` array - `scanf` stores them. That's why in my case I have used `%2s` - so that the remaining space is there for storing `\0`.

<sup>1</sup> Here note one thing from [reference](http://Always%20stores%20a%20null%20character%20in%20addition%20to%20the%20characters%20matched%20(so%20the%20argument%20array%20must%20have%20room%20for%20at%20least%20width+1%20characters)) under `%s` format specifier

> matches a sequence of non-whitespace characters (a string)
>   If width specifier is used, matches up to width or until the first whitespace character, whichever appears first. ***Always stores a null character in addition to the characters matched (so the argument array must have room for at least `width+1` characters).***

Note: As pointed by Simon Berthiaume in comment -

> You can write string length like this: `char year[4+1];`, that way it is clear what the content size is intended to be. For example in this case it is 4 digit year that you wanted.

Comment: @alk.: Yes precisely what you said. Edited.

Comment: Again about structure: From the question it is quiet obvious that the OP has no idea about what makes a "string" in C. Your question talks about `0`s in the beginning, which would most likely not make any sense to the OP, and only at the end you explains what it is all about. So this is the exception to the rule we found some hours ago. No rule without exception ... ;-)

Comment: Thank you I understood what you want to say. :-) @coderredoc

Comment: I am working and trying to know things and I am actually new to programming. Doing my assignment and trying to learn from all of you. This community is great. @alk

Comment: An old "trick" we used to have back in my C programming days is to write string length like this: `char year[4+1];`, that way it was even clearer when the content size was intended to be.

Comment: @SimonBerthiaume.: That's a nice one - do you want me to add it to the answer?

Comment: "*... writer I am*" I am sure you improve every day.

Comment: @coderredoc Be my guest to add it to your answer :)